# Select All checkbox problem in asp.net mvc project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

[image]

In here these checkboxes I select manually and press the sync button, at the time it works properly, but I press the select all button, all the checkboxes are selected but not sync.

**this is select all button and function**

```
<div class="col">
  <label style="padding:10px 0 0 8px">
    <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="input[]" onClick="toggle(this)">
    <span class="ml-2">Select All</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

**This is script part**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(source) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
        for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked =source.checked;

        }
    }
</script>
```

**This is checkboxes**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:SHTYP_IS_MANUAL_SYNC"
        class="i-checks" name="foo"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toggle(checked) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
     for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].checked !=source.checked) {
       checkboxes[i].click();
   }
```

}
}

Comment: It's work perfectly.. thank you so much @erdi

Answer (score 0):

you are using click event which occur when user click on checkbox,
but we need to use onchange event in your JavaScript source code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.i-checks').change(function() 
  {
    toggle(this)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried in the first one and it's work,